# Is there a better way of finding something when webscraping

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I was curious as whether there is a better way of finding an element when webscraping instead of using xpath as websites are likely to change and i'd prefer if my program was good enough to withstand a few small updates in the html. Currently I am finding the most recent transaction made on an account and just scraping a few bits of info such as price and who from. It is all working just want a more efficient way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import asyncio,discord,datetime
from discord.ext import commands

url = "https://etherscan.io/address/0x7ef865963d3a005670b8f8df6aed23e456fa75e0"
xpaths = ['//*[@id="transactions"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]','//*[@id="transactions"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a']


def main():
    driver_options = Options()
    driver_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("Drivers\Chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)

    results = {}
    try:
        for i in xpaths:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,i)))
            results[i] = element.get_attribute("textContent")
    finally:
        driver.quit()
        
    with open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","r") as f:
        info = f.readlines()
        info = info[0].split(",")
    f.close()

    if int(results[xpaths[0]][:-6:]) > int(info[0][:-6:]):
        print("higher")
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        with open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(f"{results[xpaths[0]]},{results[xpaths[1]]},{current_time}")
        f.close()

    print(results)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This code should work perfectly to get the information. If there are any issues, comment, and I will see if anything must be changed.

Comment: _websites are likely to change_ This is exactly why webscraping is so fragile.  Does the website offer an API?  If so, that will probably be a much better option.

Comment: It does have an API, [link]( https://etherscan.io/apis) however I dont believe there is a python version of it.

Comment: I would assume the API accepts and returns some standard format (likely json), so you could certainly use python.

Comment: @B1ake, your above comment is actually incorrect. There are no "python" version or "java" version for APIs. Since an API is a universally accessible artifact, you can use any API client in any programming language. By looking at the https://etherscan.io/apis i can see these APIs return JSON messages. So you can directly use them with your python code